# jQuery UI tabs: hidden elements are shown in IE7

Tags: jquery-ui, jquery-ui-tabs, internet-explorer-7

The problem happens only in IE7:
When I go to the next tab some elements (text input fields, buttons) from the previous tab are not completely 'hidden' and shown on the next tab (just on top of it). Buttons disappear when I mouse over them, but text inputs stay there forever.

I am using jQuery 1.4 and JqueryUI 1.8

Has anyone seen that problem before?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i faced the same problem before. My advice - begin with empty tabs, then add step-by-step all elements to their tab-containers. one of them is parsed incorrectly by ie.

Comment: It was not an issue. The problem was with my custom animation: I made some custom animated transition between the tabs and it looks that for some reason elements don't get hidden well during the animation. But since you made me go through my code, I'll mark it as answer.